# Powershell Modules: Get-Module -All vs Get-InstalledModule

Tags: powershell-4.0

When I run Get-InstalledModule I see Version 3.0.1 of a module that I'm interested in.  When I run "Get-Module -all" I see 2.7.1 of that same module.

So which one is actually being used?  How can I clean-up and remove the old 2.7.1 version?

Comment: I found the Get-Module -ListAvailable, and that shows me which directories the modules are in, so I'm going to try deleting some of those directories.

Comment: Well, that's not wise - as there is a PSGetModuleInfo.xml that must be used to show the version numbers. So what is the proper remove command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Running Get-Module without the -ListAvailable parameter shows only what's been imported into the current PowerShell session. These could be modules you've imported manually using the "Import-Module" command, or ones that were imported automatically (in PowerShell v3 and up) once you tried running a command from one of them.

Get-InstalledModule shows all installed modules. The most recent version should auto-import by default, but if you want to clean up old versions, use the command "Uninstall-Module -Name modulename -RequiredVersion version", to specify the version you want to uninstall.